# How can I add a comment with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, comments, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to create a data structure with ruamel.yaml and want to add comments **before** dumping and/or loading it again.
Unfortunately all examples load some string with the round trip dumper first or use no longer existing APIs.

This is what I am trying to dump:

```
test: asdf # Test Comment!
```

I tried the following:

```py
insert = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
start_mark = ruamel.yaml.error.CommentMark(0)
insert['test'] = 'asdf'
insert.ca.items['test'] = [ None,
    [ruamel.yaml.CommentToken(value='# Test Comment!', start_mark=start_mark, end_mark=None)],
    None,
    None
]
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(insert, sys.stdout)
```

which prints.

```
# Test Comment!test: asdf
```

Somehow the comment is in front instead of behind the values.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to do this by adding the `CommentTokens`, but the
start_mark type would have to be comming from `ruamel.yaml.error`.

It is much more easy to make `insert` a `CommentedMap` (which is what 
the mapping would get loaded as, when doing a normal, round-trip, load),
and then use its `yaml_add_eol_comment` method:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


insert = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
insert['test'] = 'asdf'
insert.yaml_add_eol_comment('Test Comment!', 'test', column=0)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(insert, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
test: asdf # Test Comment!
```

The `column=0` is optional. If you don't specify the start column,
you'll get two spaces before the `#`, 0 tries to push it all the way to the front, but of course the key-value pair is in the way.

You can specify the `#` in the
EOL comment you specify to the `yaml_add_eol_comment` method, but if
it is not there, it will be prepended.

If you have multiple comments after multiple keys on consecurive
lines, and want your comments to align, you only have to specify the
column of the first one added.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this does solve it. Somehow I missed the ```yaml_add_eol_comment``` method of ```CommentedMap```

Comment: I don't think that is in the documentation, that is what  happens when the developer of a library is a lazy guy.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the latest documents, https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html

The `CommentedMap`, which is the `dict` like construct one gets when round-trip loading, supports insertion of a key into a particular position, while optionally adding a comment:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_str = """\
key: value # first line and comment!
"""

yaml = YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data.insert(1, 'test', 'asdf', comment="Test Comment!")
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
key: value # first line and comment!
test: asdf # Test Comment!
```

Comment: I guess I should sometimes read the documentation and not just write it. Caveat: although this works, it doesn't give you the control over the column in which the comment starts. If you had loaded a line without comment, your `# Test Comment!` would have two spaces between `asdf` and `#`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't load the yaml string because it does not exist yet so this does not solve my problem.